# driver.get is ignored on second data set of Testng test

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

The code in the "basePageNavigation" @Test is running fine on the first data set, but when the method is ran the second time, the first line in it:

driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

is ignored, and thus the test fails on the first findElement method called. When I run this in debug mode having a breakpoint at that line, it works fine. Code:

```
package Academy;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObjects.ForgotPassword;
import pageObjects.Landingpage;
import pageObjects.Loginpage;
import resources.base;

public class Homepage extends base{
    
    public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Homepage.class.getName());
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void initialize() throws IOException
    {
        driver=initializeDriver();
        log.info("Driver initialized");
        
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void basePageNavigation(String username, String password, String text) throws IOException
    {
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        Landingpage l=new Landingpage(driver);
        Loginpage lp = l.getLogin();
        lp.getEmail().sendKeys(username);
        lp.getPassword().sendKeys(password);
        
        lp.getLoginBtn().click();
        ForgotPassword fp = lp.forgotPassword();
        fp.getEmail().sendKeys("test");
        fp.nextButton().click();
    }
    
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        //Row (first value) stands for how many different data types the test will run
        //Column (second value) stands for how many values are parsed per test
        
        Object[][] data = new Object[2][3];

        // First row
        data[0][0] = "nonResabc@qa.com";
        data[0][1] = "12345";
        data[0][2] = "Non Restricted User";
        
        //Second Row
        data[1][0] = "Resabc@qa.com";
        data[1][1] = "34567";
        data[1][2] = "Restricted User";
        
        return data;
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive been trying to find ways to fix it, adding a thread.sleep does fix it, but i think ultimately it might be an issue in the test environment.

Comment: are you running your cases in parallel?  Paste the testng suite xml or specify how ar you triggering your cases.

Comment: Thanks for replying @niharika_neo, I have solved the problem by using a different website, the one i used here had a lightning quick refresh which broke my test, I found it by trial/error